# Heroku Django error run the app

Tags: python, django, heroku

So I have tried a lot of stuff from here and from other forums, NOTHING. So please help me to resolve this kind of stuff. I am very new in python and in Django, I have created a small app, it runs perfect with  ***heroku local***  command but once I put it to the server I cant run it, this is my traceback:

```
~ $ gunicorn trydjango18.wsgi:application
2016-02-19 20:22:50 [17] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2016-02-19 20:22:50 [17] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:56762 (17)
2016-02-19 20:22:50 [17] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2016-02-19 20:22:50 [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
2016-02-19 20:22:50 [22] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/app/trydjango18/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named crispy_forms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/app/trydjango18/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named crispy_forms
2016-02-19 20:22:50 [22] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22)
2016-02-19 20:22:50 [17] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-02-19 20:22:50 [17] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
~ $
```

After I installed `crispy_forms` and ran `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
Running python manage.py collectstatic --noinput on blooming-wave-82922... !!!
 ▸    Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos.`

```
~ $ gunicorn trydjango18.wsgi:application
2016-02-19 22:36:07 [21] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2016-02-19 22:36:07 [21] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:10012 (21)
2016-02-19 22:36:07 [21] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2016-02-19 22:36:07 [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26
2016-02-19 22:36:07 [26] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/app/trydjango18/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named registration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/app/trydjango18/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named registration
2016-02-19 22:36:07 [26] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 26)
2016-02-19 22:36:08 [21] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-02-19 22:36:08 [21] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
~ $
```

Comment: Have you installed crispy_forms?

Comment: yes I did, but still have issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your base level directory for your application, you have a `requirements.txt` file that Heroku uses to install all needed libraries/packages.

The easiest way to replicate the environment you are using for development is to cd in to that dir and run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. This will create a file that mirrors your development environment. Commit and push that file to Heroku, and Heroku will install those packages and their dependencies.

For this particular error, adding a line with `django-crispy-forms` will take care of the installation.

Heroku documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip)

Comment: I have added them:

`tail requirements.txt 
Django==1.9
South==1.0
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
gunicorn==18.0
psycopg2==2.5.1
static==0.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
django-crispy-forms
`

Comment: From your terminal, while in that dir - `git commit requirements.txt -m "requirements.txt updated"` and then `git push heroku master` (assuming you set up a standard git branch named master). From there, you should see output from Heroku updating your dyno and a message once the deployment is complete. It will take (potentially) a few minutes for your new instance to start. 

In order to test for errors starting your Django app on Heroku, running `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` is a good bet.

Comment: I have updated my main question with the new output, no luck

Comment: You still have packages that Heroku doesn't know need to be installed. In this case, you need to add `django-registration-redux` to requirements.txt, commit changes, and push to Heroku again. 
It's MUCH easier to freeze your whole environment. `cd` to the base dir of your Heroku project and run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. 
Read the documentation above for a more complete explanation.

Comment: I wasn't running in `virtualenv`, so I have a looot of installed. I will try to remove the unnecessary then. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear! :) First time Django deployments can spin you in knots, but this is a good illustration of how useful virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper are. Happy Django-ing!